# Why does flow complain about untyped function parameters (missing-annot) on an exported class?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Here's some example good code:

```js
interface FooType {
  +bar: (boolean) => void
}

class Foo implements FooType {
  bar (someArg) {}
}
```

Nothing wrong here - works as expected, no errors.

Now, if we export `Foo`:

```js
interface FooType {
  +bar: (boolean) => void
}

class Foo implements FooType {
  bar (someArg) {}
}

export default Foo
```

*([Link to flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0BUCeAHFAbwChlkBqAIzigC5kAKSzAGwjhAEpkBeAPmQA3dMAAmxAL7FiCFnADO8tJmTAAtnjZqI4JRmz4ipZNSiN56bQEEoAc26EpU4hAAeedFDDJREeAFcWb30gA))*

We get the following "Missing type annotation" error:

```
6:   bar (someArg) {}
          ^ Missing type annotation for `someArg`. [missing-annot]
```

Yikes!

It's not clear to me why this would be the case. I did find [this blog post](https://medium.com/flow-type/asking-for-required-annotations-64d4f9c1edf8) about "input positions reachable from exports must be annotated", but `Foo` is typed, and thus the bar method should be explicitly typed before being exported.

Any clues as to what's going on?

Thanks!